# Element-wise comparison of numpy arrays of different lengths

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, logical-operators, elementwise-operations

I would like to compare numpy arrays of equal size in terms of greater/smaller relations. Specifically, I have

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([0.5, 2., 0.1, 12.])
>>> B = np.ones(len(A))
>>> A<B
array([ True, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
>>> C = np.array([0.5, 2., 0.1, 12., 0.8])
>>> D = np.ones(len(C))
>>> C<D
array([ True, False,  True, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

The last element is False although 0.8 is less than 1.0. This seems to happen for uneven array lengths.
Am I missing something here?

I'm using Python 2.7.6 with NumPy 1.8.0.

However, it works with NumPy 1.8.2.

Comment: cannot replicate using python 2.7 or 3

Comment: I find it hard to believe those snippets.  Your first has `A` and `B` with length 4, but the output has five elements?

Comment: I can't quite seem to reproduce this using numpy 1.8.0 and python 2.7. Can you double check your snippets please?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed something up in your test. This is always the danger when working in an interactive session. For reproducing things, you should always use a self-contained minimal working example. I guess you cannot provide this to us.

Concluding that something fails for "uneven" lengths is a bit harsh, from just one simple test :-). Also, as DSM has pointed out, in your first snippet the output does not fit the input (length-wise). You should not copy/paste unrelated input and output, just to make it look like being related, even if you *think* it was related. Let the computer tell you.

For me, things work as expected:

```
>>> A = np.array([0.5, 2., 0.1, 12., 0.8])
>>> B = np.ones(len(A))
>>> A<B
array([ True, False,  True, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I copied your code, still same problem. Which versions?

Comment: Start off with a fresh Python process, `import numpy as np`, and run the three lines. Still "invalid" output?

Comment: No worries, I've tried it several times, still same problem. However, it works perfectly with NumPy 1.8.2 on a different machine.

Comment: Still, you should fix the first snippet in your question. It makes people doubt your results, for a reason. I have skimmed through 1.8.1 release notes, if "your bug" was fixed. Don't know exactly, have a look yourself: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/release.html#numpy-1-8-1-release-notes

Comment: Snippet fixed. I couldn't find anything in the release notes.

Comment: Then now you need to test with numpy 1.8.2 and, if the problem persists, open a bug report.

Comment: Okay lets leave it here. Something seems really messed up with my NumPy installation. I just tried with ancient 2.6.8 and NumPy 1.3.0. It works perfectly. Same with 2.7.6 and NumPy 1.8.2.